# Vectorize Mean over a Column by Date within a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on creating the mean per distinct date for the column "avgPrice". The data is a panel that contains the below columns for different "typeID's". Where only typeID 18 is shown, there are 59 typeID's in the entire dataset. A sample of the data looks like the following:

```
   typeID        date  lowPrice  highPrice  avgPrice  volume  orders
0      18  2003-10-01      14.0       14.0      14.0  284846      84
1      18  2003-10-02      14.0       16.0      15.0  533151      64
2      18  2003-10-03      15.0       15.0      15.0  247490      85
3      18  2003-10-04      15.0       15.0      15.0  367424     117
4      18  2003-10-05      14.0       14.0      14.0  923101     112
```

The length of the dataframe is 24574045 and is thus quite large. What I'm trying to do is create an aggregated avgPrice column that takes the unweighted mean of the avgPrice for every typeID per date. The following code works but is extremely slow in its execution time:

```
dfm = pd.DataFrame()
total = len(set(df["date"])) # check execution time

for i, j in enumerate(set(df["date"])):
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print(i / total * 100) # check execution time
    dfm["date"] = j
    dfm["avgPrice"] = df.loc[df["date"] == j]["avgPrice"].mean()
```

This will return a new dataframe with the unweighted mean of the avgPrice over all typeID's with corresponding date. However, considering the length of the data at hand this takes a very long time to execute. Is there any way I could speed up this process, e.g. vectorize the for-loop?

Comment: `df.groupby(['typeId', 'date']).avgPrice.mean()`?

Comment: @coldspeed That just returns a condensed version of the original dataframe and doesn't take the mean "avgPrice" over all "typeID's" unfortunately.

Comment: That's exactly what it is supposed to do. Can you please be specific about why this "condensed" version is not what you're looking for (AKA, the mean over two columns which is exactly what your post asked for)?

Comment: @coldspeed When I try and run the code you've provided it doesn't average the avgPrice over all typeID's and returns a dataframe with the same length as the original dataframe.

Comment: Please do `df = df.groupby(['typeId', 'date']).avgPrice.mean()`, that was the point, you need to assign it back.

Comment: @coldspeed This is what I've done, the resulting output does not take the mean avgPrice over all typeID's.

Comment: If it's just over all typeIds (and not date), then you need `df.groupby(['typeId']).avgPrice.mean()`... your question wasn't super clear on whether you wanted to group on one column or both.

Comment: @coldspeed That gives me an attribute error. I hope that it would be clear what I intend on doing by the sample code that I'm providing? That code works and does the job, however, it is slow.